# svg fade-in text, fade-out text, and continue doing the same with new text, for set time-periods

Tags: svg, svg-animate

I want to modify code-related as follows:

1. I want `Word 1` to fade-in for 0.2 seconds, then stay on screen for 4.6 seconds, then fade-out for 0.2 seconds (i.e. a total of 5 seconds)
2. `Word 1` stays off until `Word 2` (below) fades-out.
3. Next, I want to introduce `Word 2`in the same way: fade-in for 0.2 seconds, then stay on screen for 4.6 seconds, then fade-out for 0.2 seconds (i.e. a total of 5 seconds)
4. `Word 2` stays off until `Word 1` fades-out. `Word 1` reappears as described in points 1 and 2.
5. And infinite repeat/cycle 1, 2, 3, 4 in the same sequence.

Note: Only one word is on the screen at one time, and they appear and disappear cyclically, sequentially.

Please advise.

```html
  
  
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="-180 5 700 300" xmlns="w3.org/2000/svg"; xmlns:xlink="w3.org/1999/xlink"; version="1.1"> 
  <path id="path" d="m0,110 h1100"/> 
    
  <text font-size="30" font-family="arial" fill="#ff5722"> 
    
    <textPath xlink:href="#path"><tspan fill-opacity="0"><animate id="animation1" attributeName="fill-opacity" dur="2s" to="1" fill="remove" repeatCount="indefinite"/>Word 1 </tspan>
          
    </textPath> 
  </text> 
</svg>
```

Comment: you'll want some keyTimes and values then.

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks for the clarification-request. I've added some more context to the OP. When `Word 2` appears, `Word 1` stays out of the screen until `Word 2` fades out. When `Word 1` re-appears, `Word 2` stays out of the screen until `Word 1` fades out. And so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something with keyTimes and keySplines. Like this perhaps...

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="-180 5 700 300" xmlns="w3.org/2000/svg"; xmlns:xlink="w3.org/1999/xlink"; version="1.1"> 
  <path id="path" d="m0,110 h1100"/> 
    
  <text font-size="30" font-family="arial" fill="#ff5722"> 
    
    <textPath xlink:href="#path"><tspan fill-opacity="0"><animate id="animation1" begin="0s;animation2.end" attributeName="fill-opacity" dur="5s" values="0;1;1;0" keyTimes="0;0.04;0.96;1"/>Word 1 </tspan>
    </textPath> 
  </text> 
  <text font-size="30" font-family="arial" fill="#ff5722"> 
    
    <textPath xlink:href="#path"><tspan fill-opacity="0"><animate id="animation2" begin="animation1.end" attributeName="fill-opacity" dur="5s" values="0;1;1;0" keyTimes="0;0.04;0.96;1"/>Word 2 </tspan>
    </textPath> 
  </text> 
</svg>
```